# to use loop controller to access the rows from CSV sequencially

Tags: jmeter

I am new to J meter, i have a question like prepared a CSV as shown below, Now i want to use loop controller to access the rows from CSV sequencially. Please help on this. I need to execute loop for 5 times and each loop has to pick next row.

Fname       Lname
   west1         east1
   west2        east2
   west3        east3

Please help me the settings to use loop counter for the same.

Thanks,
VB

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you need it to assign the variable? or you are trying to pull CSV data in your test case. Can you also provide the structure or screenshot of your current test case?

Comment: Refer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093282/how-to-use-csv-data-set-config-inside-a-while-loop-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the examples provided with JMeter. See the example of CSV reading in %JMETER_HOME%\bin\examples\CSVSample.jmx. It is pretty simple and obvious case.