# Passing only the required rows of data from CSV file to Jmeter based on a criteria

Tags: javascript, csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a csv file which has the input in the below format (It has no headers as first row):

```
India,QA,1200,
India,QA1,1201,
India,QA2,1202,
USA,Dev1,5580,
USA,Dev2,5580,
AUS,Dev3,3300,
AUS,Dev4,3301,
```

I have configured the `CSV Data Set Config` component and have given the respective path and variable name details. Snapshot below:

[image]

from the command line argument, i will be invoking the Jmeter `jmeter.bat -t C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\JI\testscript.jmx -JCountry=India`which also has a parameter called `JCountry=India`.

Now, I have to use this value (India) and then search the csv file's first column and if it matches, I need to send only those particular rows matching to the country name given from the cmd to the script.

I thought of using `If Controller` but how can I check the csv files first row and when there is a match, send those details to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through CSV, see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093282/how-to-use-csv-data-set-config-inside-a-while-loop-in-jmeter)  or [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755384/jmeter-loop-through-all-values-in-csv).
As the second example use in while condition the variable from CSV: ${Country} .

Inside loop you need to add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with condition to compare country variable against country property:

```
 ${__jexl3("${__P{Country}" == "${Country}")}
```

> Checking this and using __jexl3 or __groovy function in Condition is advised for performances

Comment: I am using a While Controller having the condition set as `${__P{Country}` , next have the CSV file clubbed to it and then to that using an IF Controller having the condition as `${__jexl3("${__P{Country}" == "${Country}")}`. how will only those particular lines of the csv files go further. will this be sufficient ?

Comment: As the second example use in while condition the variable from CSV: `${Country}` . Using property will return always true and will loop forever

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be dynamically generating a CSV file with only `India` lines

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler to the setUp Thread Group (this way you won't have an extra result in .jtl file)
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as a child of the Test Action Sampler
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   String country = props.get('Country')

   def originalCsvFile = new File('C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/JI/JVMDetails/Details.txt')
   def countryCsvFile = new File('C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/JI/JVMDetails/Country.txt')

   countryCsvFile.delete()

   originalCsvFile.eachLine {line ->
       if (line.startsWith(country)) {
           countryCsvFile << line
           countryCsvFile << System.getProperty('line.separator')
       }
   }
   ```
5. Configure your CSV Data Set Config to use `C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\JI\JVMDetails\Country.txt` as this file will have only those lines which start with what you have defined as `Country` property

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Groovy Goodness: Working with Files](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-files.html)