# jmeter - how to creat new csv from original csv with groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a csv file (UTF-8 with BOM) like this

```
NAME,F1,F2,
test1,field1,field2
test2,field1,field2
test3,field1,field2
test4,field1,field2
test5,field1,field2
test6,field1,field2
```

I would like to discard the first three lines and create new csv (UTF-8 with BOM)

```
NAME,F1,F2,
test4,field1,field2
test5,field1,field2
test6,field1,field2
```

I get some idea from [the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47430827/12659479) and code this in JSR223 PreProcessor

```
def originalCsvFile = new File('g:/Workspace/1.csv')
def newCsvFile = new File('g:/Workspace/2.csv')


originalCsvFile.readLines().take(5).each {line ->
    newCsvFile.withWriter('UTF-8') { writer ->   
        writer.writeLine line
    }
  }
```

The above code does not work.
It is better to put the new csv path to the variable, I want to get the variable in jmeter CSV Data Set Config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you realize that:

1. `take(5)` function [returns 5 first lines of the list](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#take(int))
2. newCsvFile.withWriter function [overwrites the file with the new data](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#withWriter(groovy.lang.Closure)) each time it's being called

So I believe you're looking for copying and pasting something like this:

```
originalCsvFile.readLines().eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    if (index == 0 || index > 3) {
        newCsvFile.withWriterAppend('UTF-8') { writer ->
            writer.writeLine line
        }
    }
}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Correct on 1 and 2

Comment: Thanks. it works, but the newCsvFile without  BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant, perhaps, but this is how I would do it:

```
List li = originalCsvFile.readLines()
newCsvFile.append(li[0] + "\n", 'UTF-8') //headers
li[4..-1].each { newCsvFile.append(it + "\n", 'UTF-8') }
```